# Change resolution of a procedural texture without baking

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I want to change the resolution of a noise texture node so it is 24x24 pixels for a Minecraft procedural material I'm working on, I have no idea how to do it but basically, I want to "rasterize" the noise texture without baking it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out, I had to use some vector math:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and describe with words how it works. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sorry for not having a clear question @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , but I already found a solution to the problem but thank you!